# resetting timeout timer of expect, while output is received from a send command

Tags: expect

Is it possible to reset the timeout timer while the command issued with "send" is printing it's output?

The case is that I'd like to run in many servers a command like `find / -exec head {} /;`. I want the timer to reset while the command prints output. I don't like to set the timeout to hours...

Thanks!

Comment: Just set `timeout` to a new value after you get output from the command.

Answer (score 2):

With `exp_continue`, this can is possible.

```
set threshold 1
set timeout 60; # 1 min
send "find / -exec head {} / \r"
expect {
    # Your prompt here
    "#"; {puts "prompt matched. cmd completed"}
    timeout {
        # Checking for max of 10 mins 
        if {$threshold>10} {
            puts "output took more time than threshold"
            exit 1
        }
        incr threshold
        puts "Still waiting for the prompt"
        # The below command will reset the expect timer 
        # and will cause the same expect loop to run again
        exp_contintue;
    }
}
```